# MySQL - addition, subtraction and counting the days

Tags: php, mysql

I want to calculate the average number of sold products. Table:

```
pieces | date                | status
-------------------------------------------
1      | 2015-07-27 12:00:01 | sold
2      | 2015-07-27 16:30:43 | sold
1      | 2015-07-28 13:17:11 | sold
1      | 2015-07-29 10:46:00 | returned
```

I must add all pieces with "sold" status (4), substract all "returned" (1) and divide (2015-07-29 - 2015-07-27) 3.

Can I make this with one query like:

```
SELECT SUM(pieces WHERE 'sold' - pieces WHERE 'returned' / date(max - min)) WHERE (date >= date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 days))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  An easy way is with conditional aggregation:

```
select (sum(case when status = 'sold' then pieces else 0 end) -
        sum(case when status = 'returned' then - pieces else 0 end)
       ) / (1 + datediff(max(date), min(date))
from . . .;
```

Comment: select (sum(case when statuses_storages_parts_pieces LIKE 'sold%' then statuses_storages_parts_pieces else 0 end) -
        sum(case when statuses_storages_parts_pieces LIKE 'returned%' then - statuses_storages_parts_pieces else 0 end)
       ) / (1 + datediff(max(statuses_storages_date), min(statuses_storages_date))) from aso_storages_statuses ---- result 0.0000 :-/